# Accessing the native camera app from the browser on Windows 10 devices

Tags: javascript, windows, html, browser, image-capture

Taking a photo from the browser on an Android or iOS device isn't hard, as we all know. Just use a file input field and add a parameter called *capture*. However, as far as I know, not a single browser for Windows 10 does support that tag.

The requirement is to take high-res photos on a Surface Pro tablet and annotate them immediately from within a website. Right now, I'm using getVideoTracks as a halfhearted fallback for Windows devices. This, though, has some serious drawbacks, namely a significantly reduced image resolution (only 2 MP) and a great loss in color depth and control over the camera, just to name two of them. Switching between the native camera app and the website and uploading the pictures through a regular file input is also not an option in our productive environment.

Is there any way to trigger the native camera app on a Surface Pro from JavaScript and use the captured photos immediately? Or a browser which already supports the ImageCapture API? Chrome crashes with the error message *"DOMException: setOptions failed"*, even when running the official samples, which seems to be a known bug for ages. Or is there a Windows browser which supports the capture attribute on input fields?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: hi! have you solved this?

Comment: @Anton Nope, unfortunately not. No idea, if it is possible in the mean time.